# how use one DBcontext for each user

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

i want use Db Context for each user in my MVC project with code first.

when user come to my web site one Db context allocated to the user and when user log out from my web site and close browser , user's Db Context Be destroyed.

how can i do this?

Comment: Why? It seems like you'd end up with a lot of unreleased resources.

Comment: hi.i want manage my db context don't open and close for each controller or request. i want have one db context for each user up to have good speed for select and insert for each user .

Comment: @user2704932 by doing what you are suggesting you are likely to get the opposite. Its likely to be slower and less responsive for your users